# Python 2.7 Argparse Optional and Required arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments

So I've been frantically reading tutorials on argparse everywhere but can't seem to figure out why my program is getting an error. My code currently looks like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "-debug", required = False, help = "optional parameter")
parser.add_argument("input_file", help = "file to be parsed")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I run my program with the command "python myprogram.py -d inputfile" it complains that there are too few arguments. Furthermore, when I just run it with inputfile as the parameter, it works.

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [default action](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#action) for an argument is `'store'`.  `store` actions generally expect a *value* to be associated with the flag.

It looks like you want this to be a boolean switch type of flag in which case you want the `'store_true'` action

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-d", "--debug", required = False, help = "optional parameter", action = "store_true")
parser.add_argument("input_file", help = "file to be parsed")
args = parser.parse_args()
```